# Can't fill the attribute table programmatically

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, vba

I've got a shp-file, here is it's attribute table:

[image: Attribute table]

It's easy to fill the attribute table of some `pFeature` programmatically if I get the feature from cursor:

For example, "RECNO" Field(3) has a numeric format

```
Set pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
Set pFeature.Value(3) =2
pFeature.store
```

Usually, it works fine, I shouldn't even start the Edit session for this.

But when I add a new feature and try to fill the attribute table in this code below, the error "Object required" appears.

```
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pFeature As IFeature
Dim pFeatureClass1 As IFeatureClass
Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
Set pFeatureLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
Set pFeatureClass1 = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass

Set pFeature = pFeatureClass1.CreateFeature

' HERE IS THE PROBLEM
Set pFeature.Value(3) = 2
```

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the code you have:

```
Set pFeature.Value(3) = 2
```

needs to be

```
pFeature.Value(3) = 2
```

The reason is that the value it is storing is a number and not an object.

If you are planning to run this in a loop, consider using an `IFeatureBuffer` with an insert cursor, I believe these are faster. Below is some example code from an old project of mine.

```
        For i = 0 To aDict.Count - 1
            Let aKey = thekeys(i)         ' aKey is dist from route mouth
            Set pPoint = aDict.Item(aKey) ' point
            Set pFeatureBuffer = pFeatureClass_Output.CreateFeatureBuffer
            Set pFeatureBuffer.Shape = pPoint
            With pFeatureBuffer
                .Value(.Fields.FindField("ID")) = spID
                .Value(.Fields.FindField("Dist2Mouth")) = aKey
                .Value(.Fields.FindField("PolylineID")) = pFeature_WB.OID
                .Value(.Fields.FindField("WBID")) = WBID
            End With
            Let spID = spID + 1
            pFeatureCursor_SP.InsertFeature pFeatureBuffer
        Next i
```

Comment: you are right, it works!  Hornbydd,  thanks a lot!